# purging old kernels fails to remove old initrd files

Tags: kernel

Can't explain why... I assume it isn't safe to simply manually delete them, so some guidance would be appreciated. Here's a ls of my /boot directory (obviously, I'm running the 3.13.0-51 kernel):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1164671 Apr 15 09:03 abi-3.13.0-51-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165762 Apr 15 09:03 config-3.13.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Apr 30 14:33 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22431280 Nov 26 14:16 initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22427261 Nov 26 14:16 initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9098067 Nov 26 18:00 initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9109727 Feb  5 15:22 initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9110419 Jan 18 02:29 initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9109659 Apr  5 23:11 initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9109097 Apr  5 23:01 initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5814104 Apr 30 14:13 initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22483793 Apr 30 13:52 initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9124331 Apr 30 14:28 initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22496134 Apr 30 13:59 initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4112384 Apr 30 12:16 initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic.old-dkms
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Aug  4  2014 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3389875 Apr 15 09:03 System.map-3.13.0-51-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5818368 Apr 15 09:03 vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
```

Comment: Damn - sorry for the formatting...

Comment: You can always edit your post and format it by highlighting the text and clicking the icon above the text-box. or wait for someone else to do it for you.

Comment: I have never had *.old-dkms files. What did you do to have them?

Comment: @jarno They get created by Dell's **DKMS** (Dynamic Kernel Management System) for modules not included in mainline kernel. For example `nvidia` and `bbsswitch` source when compiled might replace `/boot/initrd.img` so make a backup copy which can be restored if `dkms` is used to uninstall the changes. I'm working today to update my [`rm-kernels` bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077) to delete them obsolete `.old-dkms`.

Comment: @jarno As per my answer below revising the bash script is no longer required. People just need a one time manual process to delete `/boot/*.old-dkms` that belong to removed kernels.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes that feature is included in my linux-purge software.

Answer (score 10):

It is safe to remove them manually. It also looks like there is a bug report filed: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717584

I can report the same happening here with the 3.13.0-54 kernel and 3.13.0-55 kernel.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jun 17 20:03 abi-3.13.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jun 19 05:04 abi-3.13.0-57-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 162K Jun 17 20:03 config-3.13.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 162K Jun 19 05:04 config-3.13.0-57-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  12K Jul 11 15:54 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11M Jul  7 21:37 initrd.img-3.13.0-54-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27M Jul  4 13:37 initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27M Jul  4 13:37 initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27M Jul  6 18:28 initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 174K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175K Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 3.3M Jun 17 20:03 System.map-3.13.0-55-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.3M Jun 19 05:04 System.map-3.13.0-57-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5.6M Jun 17 20:03 vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5.6M Jun 19 05:04 vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
```

Comment: Thank you for the bug link. Upon reviewing it I discovered a fix was made upstream in April 2017. It saved me revising a bash script as I answered below.

Comment: Yes! I actually just happened to notice this morning that those old-dkms files were being successfully removed now. Nice coincidence there.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix oh, it seems my fix has made it to some Ubuntu release. The respective Launchpad bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1515513). Which version of dkms you are using?

Comment: @jarno Currently I'm running `2.2.0.3` but I have no idea what version was running when the obsolete `initrd.img*.old-dkms` files were left behind.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix dkms 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9 (in Ubuntu 14.04) seems not to have the fix. Even 16.10 uses version 2.2.0.3. So I do not know what deleted the .old-dkms files in your system.

Comment: @jarno I got the impression reading the bug fix that they were patching `update-initramfs` to delete the backup files no longer needed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Do you mean in the Launchpad bug I linked? Which version of initramfs-tools you are using? Which Ubuntu release?

Comment: @jarno I was referring to the link in the above answer we are currently commenting under. My `dkms` is only half setup and auto install has been turned off for many months. My platform is not ideal for testing. The Poster above mentioned his `.old-dkms` were getting purged automatically now. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: @Portugalthephilosoph do you use some development version of dkms and/or initramfs-tools? Which Ubuntu reiease? I am surprised, if the fix has been released in Ubuntu yet.

Comment: @jarno no, just regular ol' 16.04.3, currently on the 4.4.0-89 kernel

Comment: @Portugalthephilosoph `/var/log/dpkg*` files would tell, if `dkms` or `initramfs-tools` has been upgraded lately. The fix could be in those packages.

Comment: I do not see the fix in `dkms` or `initramfs-tools` packages of xenial-updates repository, so it is mystery to me how the old-dkms files were removed in your computer, if you did not remove the files manually.

Comment: @jarno ignore everything. Just realized that I don't even have dkms installed. I have no idea when it got removed from (ALL!) my machines or how or why, but I am reinstalling it now.

Answer (score 3):

You could run the command `rm /boot/*.old-dkms` with Root privileges. However, be sure that the removed *.old-dkms files are not needed by older kernels that you may have installed. You can see a list of your currently installed kernels by executing `dpkg-query -l "linux-image-[0-9]*" | grep -e "^ii"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was planning to modify my [`rm-kernels` bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once/892077#892077) to delete these old backups if the kernel has been removed with `sudo apt purge *<kernel_version>*`. However while researching bug reports I found this was [fixed upstream](https://github.com/dell/dkms/issues/2) in April 2017.

If you don't mind running GUI apps as root you can also use `pkexec nautilus` to find obsolete backups to delete:

[image: boot-initrd.img.old-dkms]

On my system Nautilus reveals kernel versions `4.4.8`, `4.9.21` and `4.10.10` are installed and can utilize `.old-dkms` backups. The highlighted copies are obsolete backups I deleted.

**NOTE:** `pkexec` requires policy kit setup. It is designed to replace `gksu` and `gksudo` which you will see referenced many times in historical posts.