# dpkg --configure -a unsuccessful due to battery running out of power

Tags: kernel, updates, dpkg

I was updating my system as usual and `sudo apt update` showed me some packages to be updated. I ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it downloaded the packages. But while packages were being configured during the installation, the computer was turned off due to low battery.
When I booted and tried to update using `sudo apt update` I got this message:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

When I executed `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I got this:

```
@mike-bravo:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic (4.4.0-96.119) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic) -- doing nothing at 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-
96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-96-
generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-96-generic 
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 
4.4.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-96-
generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-96-
generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 252: /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: cannot create 
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Read-only file system
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return 
code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-
image-4.4.0-96-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic (--
configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-
image-4.4.0-96-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-96-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-96-
generic (= 4.4.0-96.119); however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-96-generic (-
-configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-96.119) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to flush updated status of 'linux-libc-dev:amd64': Read-only 
file system
```

As a side effect(?) to this my system became **read-only**. I had to reboot it to be able to move files, add or copy files from the system.

`uname -r` gives me *4.4.0-93-generic*

How can I delete this un-configured package (*linux-image-4.4.0-96-
    generic*) or configure it properly?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: did you try again after rebooting?

Comment: @George I have tried that. But its giving me same message that dpkg was interrupted and I should manually configure it.

Comment: @ravery yes, at least a couple of time.

Comment: a read-only munt culd be because of a disk error. boot from a LiveCD and run file system checks on your parttions

Comment: I fixed the error running fsck manually. system has been recovered so its not a problem. The actual problem which is causing this strange behaviour is the broken package.

Comment: So you must set your own answer (with details, preferable) and close this issue.

Comment: @Redbob I would not have asked this question if I knew the solution. :-(

Comment: You might know the solution, but someone that search for a solution to this issue may not know. It's very useful, post it!

Comment: Did you try removing the specified package? Since it seems you're using another kernel version anyway, which means removing the broken one shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: You could try this answer from me aswell. https://askubuntu.com/questions/932228/cannot-remove-old-kernel-showing-error-code-1/932232#932232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've resolved the read-only mount and repaired the file system. You can clean up the mess and try again. Before doing so it would be wise to [check the SMART status of your drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077) as an impending hardware failure can make all your efforts useless. If the drive is reported to be in  good shape, it should be safe to continue.

`sudo apt-get purge linux-signed-image-generic` will purge the unconfigured, not fully installed package.

`sudo apt install linux-signed-image-generic` will install the currently supported version.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of recovering from an interrupted kernel upgrade due to battery running out of juice is to:

- ensure the laptop is connected to mains power now *and every kernel upgrade you do in the future!*
- hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting and on the following screen:
  [image: Ubuntu advanced boot screen]
- take "advanced options"
- boot into the second-to-last kernel
- do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` again.

#### Done! :-)