# Removing old kernels and reboot

Tags: grub2, kernel, reboot

I am running 17.04.

After upgrading the kernel, I usually run [Ubuntu Cleaner](http://ubuntu-cleaner.blogspot.com/) to remove old kernels.

After the old kernels are removed, the system always requests a reboot. I suspect that it has to do with the grub loader. Is there anything I can run to avoid this reboot, since I will already be running the new kernel and there should be no urgency?

Comment: Do you also run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: I do not, yet. I'll try that the next time it happens.

Comment: There is an excellent kernel removal utility [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892076/how-to-selectively-purge-old-kernels-all-at-once).

Comment: I am currently running 4.10.0-37. Can I safely delete the other kernels from `/boot` (`4.[28].*`)?

Comment: Look at the files `/var/run/reboot*` - packages requiring a reboot usually leave their names there.