# Emergency mode after kernel update from 4.15.0-76 to 4.15.0-88

Tags: boot, kernel

Can anyone help me out with the following problem? After ubuntu kernel update 4.15.0-76 to 4.15.0-88, I get in an emergency mode. I have to use the former kernel to be able to use the computer. Can´t find anything useful on current fora. I'm not sure what kind of information you need to solve this, and how to retrieve it from an emergency state system without uploading screenshots instead of plain text!?.

Comment: Did you install any grapphics drivers? Which and how?

Comment: When going into emergency mode, does it give any error messages? Is it GRUB emergency mode, or Ubuntu Recovery mode?

Comment: Thanks for responding! 1. No, I didn't install (new) graffic dirvers or other drivers

Comment: 2. I don know; The screen says; code; You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type ´journalctl -xb´ to view system logs code. I have a photo of blkid output and cat ..etc/fstab output but cannot upload it! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I lost wifi from the -88 kernel upgrade, so I went back to -76.

Comment: It would help OP if you tell how you went back to previous version. Also you should look at "pinning" the good kernel version so it doesn't get removed in a future update. Finally you should look at having grub automatically select the last boot option instead of most recent kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003079/how-to-change-the-order-on-my-dual-booting-distros/1003086#1003086

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix; your earlier suggestion/code is very helpful! sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic [https://askubuntu.com/questions/999529/pin-kernel-version]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing the options in my fstab for a 2nd drive that mounts at boot.

UUID= /mountpoint ext4 defaults 0 1

Comment: Thanks for responding, after trying different solutions, I finally did a clean install. I think a dual boot partition was the problem and had a conflict with the update. How I don know. I'm up and running again.